# Sheets script to list cell value with a condition

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

My script currently displays V2:V in the tradeId prompt, but I want it to also display the corresponding X2:X value depending on the tradeId selected in V2:V, in the amount prompt. Below is the data set/ script.

```
var amount = validateNumericInput('Enter the amount:');
```

[image]

```html
function closeTrade() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var tradeId = Browser.inputBox('Enter the Trade ID to close:' + sheet.getRange("V2:V").getValues().filter(String), Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
  if (tradeId == "cancel") {
    return;
  }
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  var openAmount = 0; // initialize open amount to zero
  var closeAmount = 0; // initialize close amount to zero
  var columnKValues = sheet.getRange("K:K").getValues(); // get values in column K

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i][0] == tradeId) {
      if (values[i][2].toLowerCase() == "open") {
        openAmount += values[i][3]; // add open amount to the total open amount
      } else if (values[i][2].toLowerCase() == "close") {
        closeAmount += values[i][3]; // add close amount to the total close amount
      }
    }
  }


  
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i][0] == tradeId) {
      if (values[i][2].toLowerCase() == "open") {
        var openRow = sheet.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, values[0].length).getValues();
        var amount = validateNumericInput('Enter the amount:');
        if (amount == null) {
          return;
        }
        var correspondingKValue = columnKValues[i][0];
        if (correspondingKValue < amount) { // check if Column K value is less than the close amount
          Browser.msgBox('Close amount cannot be greater than the remaining amount.');
          return;
        }
        var exitPrice = validateNumericInput('Enter the Exit Price (numerical only):');
        if (exitPrice == null) {
          return;
        }
        
        var description = Browser.inputBox('Description:', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
        if (description == "cancel") {
          return;
        }
        sheet.appendRow([tradeId, openRow[0][1], "close", amount, openRow[0][4], exitPrice, description]);
        return;
      } else if (values[i][2].toLowerCase() == "close") {
        Browser.msgBox('This trade has already been closed.');
        return;
      }
    }
  }
  Browser.msgBox('Trade ID not found.');
}
```

I'm stumped on the changes I would have to make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the best way to do this would be to build a message first, this can be done like this:

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var data1 = sheet.getRange("V2:V").getValues().filter(String)
  var data2 = sheet.getRange("X2:X").getValues().filter(String)
  var message  = "Open Trades ----- Amount \\n \\n"
    for (let i = 0; i < data1.length; i++){
    message += data1[i] + " ----- " + data2[i] + "\\n \\n"
  }
  Browser.inputBox(message)
```

While doing the script I noticed that for some reason the inputBox does not recognize multiple spaces or the tab scape sequence (/t or //t) so I added the dashes (-----) to separate each number in a way that's easier to understand, feel free to change that in any way you prefer.

Here is the full script which includes all of the the data you had in your question:

```
function closeTrade() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data1 = sheet.getRange("V2:V").getValues().filter(String) //Obtaining data from the "Open Trades" row
  var data2 = sheet.getRange("X2:X").getValues().filter(String) //Obtaining data from the "Amount" row
  var message  = ""         //Declaring the "Message" variable
    for (let i = 0; i < data1.length; i++){
    message += data1[i] + " ----- " + data2[i] + "\\n \\n" //Building the full message to be used on Browser.inputBox
  }
  var tradeId = Browser.inputBox('Enter the Trade ID to close: \\n \\n Open Trades ----- Amount \\n \\n' + message, Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
  if (tradeId == "cancel") {
    return;
  }
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  var openAmount = 0; // initialize open amount to zero
  var closeAmount = 0; // initialize close amount to zero
  var columnKValues = sheet.getRange("K:K").getValues(); // get values in column K

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i][0] == tradeId) {
      if (values[i][2].toLowerCase() == "open") {
        openAmount += values[i][3]; // add open amount to the total open amount
      } else if (values[i][2].toLowerCase() == "close") {
        closeAmount += values[i][3]; // add close amount to the total close amount
      }
    }
  }


  
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i][0] == tradeId) {
      if (values[i][2].toLowerCase() == "open") {
        var openRow = sheet.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, values[0].length).getValues();
        var amount = validateNumericInput('Enter the amount:');
        if (amount == null) {
          return;
        }
        var correspondingKValue = columnKValues[i][0];
        if (correspondingKValue < amount) { // check if Column K value is less than the close amount
          Browser.msgBox('Close amount cannot be greater than the remaining amount.');
          return;
        }
        var exitPrice = validateNumericInput('Enter the Exit Price (numerical only):');
        if (exitPrice == null) {
          return;
        }
        
        var description = Browser.inputBox('Description:', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
        if (description == "cancel") {
          return;
        }
        sheet.appendRow([tradeId, openRow[0][1], "close", amount, openRow[0][4], exitPrice, description]);
        return;
      } else if (values[i][2].toLowerCase() == "close") {
        Browser.msgBox('This trade has already been closed.');
        return;
      }
    }
  }
  Browser.msgBox('Trade ID not found.');
}
```

Comment: Works! Though the amount shows on the tradeId prompt. Is there a way to also show the amount on the next prompt based on the selected tradeId?

var amount = validateNumericInput('Enter the amount:');

Comment: solved! disregard above comment